# How to use remote git-repos for git clone --reference

Tags: git

I want to speed up cloning of some git-repos in my network using a cache.
I set up the repo and run git-daemon.

Now I can call

```
git clone git://my_ip/my_repo
```

What fails though is

```
git clone --reference git://my_ip/my_repo git://github.com/my_repo.git
```

with

```
fatal: path 'git://my_ip/my_repo' does not exist
```

Is there a way to use remote repositories for `--reference`?
Or do I need the reference locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--reference` is only about local repositories. See the docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---reference-if-ableltrepositorygt:

> If the reference repository is on the local machine, automatically setup .git/objects/info/alternates to obtain objects from the reference repository.

Comment: I had hoped that the manual inferred that doing it on a non-local repo would be less performant but still work.